# In a framework such as MVC, where should you place the HTML tags (body, header, html)?

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, frameworks, tags

In a framework, several parts of the HTML may be spread all over the project file. I am new to the MVC model and I am now realizing that I do not know the standards of where to place HTML tags, given the different files.

I started out by placing the HTML, head, header, body, and footer tags on my index.php file. I soon realized that I cannot alter my include files depending on the page I am showing. The result is that several files are being loaded even though they are not needed. I also saw that I won't be able to change my header because of this design.

What are the guidelines when it comes to dealing with this?

Comment: Then wouldn't I have the same problem of loading all of my unneeded files?

Comment: HTML should ho in templates, that are then managed by View classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your HTML code in view files.

```
/application/views
```

Comment: but if I have <meta> tags to add, then I would need to update each every view in my project?

Comment: for that you have to use dynamic variable for meta title and meta tags.
and pass dynamic value for each page from conroller

Comment: Then I would have to define the meta tags for each dynamic variable. No different from adding them one by one. It might be okay for a simple project, but I don't see how that would be easy for bigger projects

Comment: To make it dynamic you must have to pass it from controller.
so you have to create one heade.php file and put all html code in it and include it in whatever page you want.

and use variable for meta title and meta tag so you  have to create it only once and you can re use it for all page

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I would have to define the dynamic variable again and again. If I wanted to use bootstrap or jquery using your suggestion, that means I have to write the include statements repeatedly on each controller.

Comment: Create index.php file and put like

$this->load->view(header.php);
$this->load->view(body.php);
$this->load->view(footer.php);